How do I calculate how fast water will evaporate based off how pure it is, the tempurature, and the surface area?
I am doing a project where I distill ocean-water, I have found a formula for how to calculate evaporation rate for freshwater with its temperature, the relative humidity, temperature, and speed of air flowing over it, but nothing with ocean water. If it helps, I am using a tank-like, contained vessel to boil the water. The attached picture looks close to the tank I am using, mine is just smaller and has a pipe out the top to condense the steam.(I initially posted this in physics, but was told to post here)

The temperature of liquid seawater doesn't get higher than the boiling point.What's the boiling point - it depends on atmospheric pressure and salt content. If there's nothing which causes pressure rise during the boiling and you work at sea level the boiling point is maybe 3 or 4 degrees above 100 degrees centigrade depending on the salt content.
How much you get steam per second depends on the heating power you can put to the water. You can directly calculate it based on the vaporization heat of water.
If you do not use an electric immersion heater, but something else it can be tricky to calculate how much heat you can input to the water per a second. It depends so much on what's between the water and the source of the heat and how high is the temperature of the source of the heat. In addition all heat leaked to the ambient air is off from the vaporization power. How much heat is lost depends in a complex way on the used materials, structure and environmental conditions.
I'm afraid nobody can tell any formula which already knows the right numerical heat transfer parameters of your forthcoming system. You must measure them by yourself by making tests. I mean finding by trial and error how much heating you need above the calculated heat based on vaporization rate goal.
An exact 3D model including all dimensions and materials and a high cost physics simulation software could predict how your system will work, but even it cannot know the effect of your operating environment (temperature, air moisture, wind) which surely isn't by any means normalized to laboratory conditions.
